# Formatting integers with comma separator using openpyxl and to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am writing DataFrames to excel using `to_excel()`. I need to use openpyxl instead of XlsxWriter, I think, as the writer engine because I need to open existing Excel files and add sheets. Regardless, I'm deep into other formatting using openpyxl so I'm not keen on changing.

This writes the DataFrame, and formats the floats, but I can't figure out how to format the int dtypes.

```py
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df = pd.DataFrame({'county':['Cnty1','Cnty2','Cnty3'], 'ints':[5245,70000,4123123], 'floats':[3.212, 4.543, 6.4555]})

fileName = "Maryland - test.xlsx"
book = load_workbook(fileName)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test', float_format='%.2f', header=False, index=False, startrow=3)
ws = writer.sheets['Test']

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Tried using this, but I think it only works with XlsxWriter:

```
intFormat = book.add_format({'num_format': '#,###'})
ws.set_column('B:B', intFormat)
```

This type of thing could be used cell-by-cell with a loop, but there's A LOT of data:

```
ws['B2'].number_format = '#,###'
```

Comment: Perhaps consider changing your data frame's integers into strings formatted by thousands, then saving it?

Comment: That works for getting the comma-formatted numbers, but creates a new problem... Excel gives an automatic warning in each cell (green triangle in corner) indicating that it's a number stored as text. If auto-warnings were turned off this wouldn't happen, but that's not a good option for me.

Comment: There's no real way to avoid the loop (whether it's in your code or in the library) as formatting **must** be set per cell. But use something like `for cell in ws['B']: cell.number_format = '#,###'`

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed by using number_fomat from openpyxl.styles

```py
from openpyxl.styles import numbers

def sth():
   #This will output a number like: 2,000.00
   cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1
```

Checkout this link for further reading [thedocs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html)